# c# deployment. application not working on some machines

Tags: c#, deployment

here is the error:

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {56A9ADF8-604D-40B7-A696-990FCFAD1E46} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Comment: Stack overflow isn't really a place to dump errors. This question almost completely lacks context.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is telling you that the COM class with CLSID 56A9ADF8-604D-40B7-A696-990FCFAD1E46 is not registered on the target machine.

To solve this work out what object that CLSID refers to and make sure it is installed and registered.

Answer (score 1):

That ID is associated with an ActiveX component called FaconServer.

Could the machines having this problem be missing this component? Could it be incorrectly registered?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your application requires a specific COM component that you are not shipping along with it and is not known to always exist on the target machines. Include the component and register it when distributing your application and it should start up fine.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the COM object you are using cannot be found in the registry.

You usually can run `regsvr32 someDll.dll` to register the COM dll.

**64-bit Computers**:
Make sure that your .exe is compiled as `x86`, so that on 64-bit computers it looks for the COM registration at the right place in the registry.